# How to store data into variable.?

Tags: javascript

```
var a=1800, b=10;
    if (a == b) {
        document.write(a - b) = c;
    }
    else if (a > b) {
        document.write(a - b) = c;
    }
    else {
        document.write("Everything is wrong.") = c;
    }
    var x = c * 100;
    document.write(x);
```

Hello friends, Can i store result of variable into "c".  if yes then why i am not able to use the data for arithmetic calculations further.
I am getting 1790 as answer from if else statement.

Comment: It is very unclear what you're trying to do. Store what result?

Comment: `var c = a - b;`? I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but your variable assignment is backwards.

Comment: What i did. I want which is greater number stored in variable "a" and "b."
so i made filter using if else statement.  This is short code i have posted.
So now i got a > b. then with else if statement document.write(a - b) = c; i got c as answer and stored into variable c.
Now i want to var x results (c * 10). But i am getting nothing.

Sorry for bad English. I am trying to learn codes (Very new in JS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That isn't really even valid JavaScript.

You're calling a function (document.write()) and then using the assignment operator on it (which you can't do).

The end results would be equivalent of writing something like `undefined = 7` since JavaScript will evaluated/execute the function first.

C is also never declared anywhere so you'll have a problem with that potentially as well.

Instead you'll want to do something like this:

```
let c; //declare C but don't assign it a value
const a = 1800;
const b = 10;
if(a === b || a > b){ //Since you're doing the same thing combine the conditions
  c = a - b;
  document.write(c);
} else {
  document.write("Somethings wrong")
}
let x = c * 100; // If c is undefined you'll get NaN similar to above, otherwise you'll get a result
document.write(x);
```

Answer (score 2):

The variable should be on the left side of the equals sign.  document.write doesn't return a value so you should do the assignment before that line.

```
else if (a > b) {
    c = a - b;
    document.write(c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should initialize your variables, then else if statement doesn't make any sense because in if your are doing the same thing which you could do with `||` OR operator.

```
const a = 1800;
const b = 10;
let c = null;
if (a == b || a > b) {
    c = (a - b) * 100;
} else {
    c = "Everything is wrong.";
}
document.write(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Document.write does not return the result of the equation, and your assignments are incorrect.  When assigning variables think of it this way:

"I have a variable C.   I would like C to store the value of Y."

So C = Y.  It's backwards from the way math does it.  ( Equation = result. )   In programming, it tends to be StorageLocation = Equation.

Why do I say tends to be?  There's got to be a language out there that doesn't hold up to that paradigm!

**Here's your updated code:**

```
var a=1800, b=10, c = 0; // Initializing c for document.write is a good practice.
    if (a == b) {
        c = a-b;
    }
    else if (a > b) {
        c = a-b; /* As the other two posters noticed ... this does the same thing as the a == b.   I am assuming you'd like to do something a little  different with the two blocks. */
    }
    else {
        c = "Everything is wrong.";
    }
    document.write(c); // "Don't Repeat Yourself" or "DRY" is good practice.
    var x = c * 100; // Note - Multiplying your string by 100 is weird.
    document.write(x);
```

Comment: Wow thats what i was looking for.
Thanks Kasem for your help.
And thanks to everyone.